# Cannot change directory evenif it exists

Tags: directory

I am trying to changed directories but I get this instead:
cd -/idea
bash: cd: -/: invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]

It is acting like it doesn't exist. What gives?

Comment: Do you have access to move into the directory? (file permissions) Try ls -l

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine you meant to type:

> cd ~/idea

and not

> cd -/idea

Notice the '-' sign. If your directory truly has a leading '-' then refer to [this POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap01.html#tag_01_11) and use:

```
cd -- -/idea
```

Comment: thanks but now the .sh file I want to start says it isn't there.

Answer (score 3):

That is because bash interprets the "-" as the start of options.

Either this is a typo and you mean to type `~` rather then `-` , or if the directory has a "-" , use "--", like so

```
cd -- -/idea
```